# Angular 8/9 why authenticated & piped image url returns empty image blob in Typescript

Tags: angular, image, pipe, interceptor

I am trying to list images next a list of user from a remote server. The server is secured, so I must send a Jwt token with each request. I have an interceptor that adds a jwt token with each request. So I have used the interceptor in a pipe to authenticate every image  using the [src] tag as follows.

`<img [src]="user.photo | authenticate | async" />`

There are no errors, but only a tiny border is displayed for each image showing that the image is empty.

[image: Sample image result]

Here is the usage of the pipe in the template:

```
<div class="media">
   <img class="img-fluid circle" [src]="user.photo | authenticate | async" />
</div>
```

Here is my Typescript pipe:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'authenticate'
})
export class AuthImagePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private authService: AuthService, // our service that provides us with the authorization token
  ) {}

  async transform(src: string): Promise<string> {

    console.log(src);

    const token = this.authService.currentUserValue.token.accessToken;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token});
    const imageBlob = await this.http.get(src, {headers, responseType: 'blob'}).toPromise();
    const reader = new FileReader();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
      reader.readAsDataURL(imageBlob);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** The offending item was the css class tag `class="img-fluid circle"`. It was giving the images dimensions 0px x 0px. So the image blobs have been loading properly all along.

Case closed!